# Reversing order of points in line using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, vertices

How to invert the sequence of the points (vertices) of a line in ArcMap so the first point becomes the last and the last the first?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In your screenshot you are currently in Modify or Edit Vertex mode.  While in that mode right-click on your line and select "Flip".

[image]

This will reverse the digitised direction of your line, putting the end point at the other end.

[image]

Comment: @StefanIordache The best way to say "Thanks" here is to upvote and accept the answer that works best for you (and upvote any other answers that you find useful).  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).